# Let $T : \mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R^n$ be a linear transformation, prove that...

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $T : \mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R^n$ be a linear transformation.
>
> 1. Prove that $T$ is injective if and only if for every linearly independent set $\{\overrightarrow v_1,\ldots,\overrightarrow v_k\}$ in $\mathbb R^m$, the set $\{T(\overrightarrow v_1),\ldots,T(\overrightarrow v_k)\}$ is linearly independent in $\mathbb R^n$.

How would I even start this? Would I need to go both ways for this proof?
Would the first step be to write the definition of a injective and linearly independent set?

Comment: Use \to for $\to$.

Comment: Yes, you should go both ways – both are very short anyway.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: take $v_1,\dots,v_k$ to be a set of linearly independent vectors. Suppose that $c_1,\dots,c_k$ are scalars such that 
$$
c_1T(v_1) +\cdots+c_k T(v_k)= 0
$$
If $T$ is injective, show that each $c_i$ must be zero.

If $T$ is not injective, show that we can find a non-zero $v$ so that $T(v)=0$. The set $\{v\}$ is linearly independent.