# How do I write this proof?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

I've tried everything, but I'm just not getting it. The steps I tried were just blatantly wrong.

> Let $T:\mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a linear transformation. Prove that $T$ is injective if and only if for every linearly independent set $\lbrace v_1,...,v_n \rbrace \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$, the set $\lbrace T(v_1),...T(v_n) \rbrace$ is also linearly independent in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Do you know how to prove if-and-only-if theorems? Usually you will have to do two separate proofs: one statement implies the other, and vice versa.

Comment: You might want to try a proof by contradiction (in both directions). Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Too late,Laars,done below. : )

Comment: possible duplicate of [Let $T$ : $R^m \to R^n$ be a linear transformation, prove that...](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1144193/let-t-rm-to-rn-be-a-linear-transformation-prove-that)

Comment: HOW IS THIS OFF TOPIC? HUH?!?

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 people probably wanted to dupe it since the user asked the same question twice, but couldn't because it had no answers. http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1144532/29335

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Claim: Let $T:\mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a linear transformation. Prove that $T$ is injective if and only if for every linearly independent set $\lbrace v_1,...,v_n \rbrace \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$, the set $\lbrace T(v_1),...T(v_n) \rbrace$ is also linearly independent in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Proof: Assume T is injective i.e. one to one. This means for every x, y $\in {R^ m}$, T(x) = T(y) iff x = y. So consider a linearly independent set of vectors in $R^ m$ .Since the set is linearly independent, $\sum_{k=1}^n {a_i v _i}$ = 0 iff for every i, $a_i$ =0. So since T is a linear transformation, $T(\sum_{k=1}^n {a_i v _i})$ = $(\sum_{k=1}^n T{a_i v _i})$ $(\sum_{k=1}^n {a_i T( v _i}))$ = T(0)=0 . Since the vectors are linearly independent, $T(\sum_{k=1}^n {a_i v _i})$ = T(0) iff for every i, $a_i$ =0. But then since  $T(\sum_{k=1}^n {a_i v _i})$ =$(\sum_{k=1}^n {a_i T( v _i}))$ , then   $(\sum_{k=1}^n {a_i T( v _i}))$ =0 iff for every i, $a_i$ = 0. But that means $\lbrace T(v_1),...T(v_n)\rbrace$ are linearly independent.
  Now assume $\lbrace T(v_1),...T(v_n) \rbrace$ are linearly independent in $R^n$ whenever $\lbrace v_1),...v_n \rbrace$ is a linearly independent set of vectors in $R^m$ . We need to show the T is injective. Assume there exists i,j  $\in N$ where $T(v_i) =T(v_j)$ , but $v_i \ne v_j$ where $v_i,v_j \in \lbrace v_1),...v_n \rbrace$ .   Consider $T(v_i)-T(v_j)=0 $ Since T is a linear transformation, $T(v_i)-T(v_j)=T(v_i-v_j)=0$.Clearly, $v_i-v_j\ne0$ by assumption. But this means there exists a linear combination of members of $\lbrace T(v_1),...T(v_n) \rbrace$ where $(\sum_{k=1}^n {a_i T( v _i}))$ =0 and there exists $a_k = +1\ne 0$ and $a_l =-1\ne 0$. But that means $\lbrace T(v_1),...T(v_n) \rbrace$ is not linearly independent, which is a contradiction! Q.E.D.

The critical thing to note here is that we proved the result **in both directions.** That's what it means to prove a theorem as an "iff" statement.

Comment: Uh,comments,questions,jokes? I hear crickets...........

Comment: You should space your proof out to make it easier to read. There are also some typos. Furthermore you assume that the $v_i$ and $v_j$ which are such that $T(v_i)=T(v_j)$ are linearly independent, which may not be so. To show that if it preserves linearly independence then it is injective, just work with the basis vectors.

Comment: @JRP I thought I'd made it clear in the proof; I assumed $v_i$ and $v_j$ were members of the linearly independent set in $R^m$ which are in the domain of T. Maybe not,I should clarify that somewhat.

Comment: Maybe I misread that.

Comment: @JRP In any event,I've clarified it.